# The length of a point and the interval

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I think the length of a point is $0$, and since [biunique corespondence between the points of [0, 1] and [0, 10]](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=UfdossHPlkgC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=that%20any%20interval%20%5BA,%20B%5D%20of%20the%20number%20axis%20is%20equivalent%20to%0D%0Aany%20other%20interval%20%5BC,%20D%5C.&source=bl&ots=Wrq535Zzk5&sig=zyBrR8gFhkWiI5_73aEGtNe1u6k&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=6VlRVerKNcWOmwXRoYGQAg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=that%20any%20interval%20%5BA%2C%20B%5D%20of%20the%20number%20axis%20is%20equivalent%20to%20%20any%20other%20interval%20%5BC%2C%20D%5C.&f=false), therefore I came to the conclusion that there is a same number of points between [0, 1] and [0, 10], if we denote the number of points with $\infty$, then I think we should get  ${0}\cdot\infty={1}$, this means both intervals have the same length 1, but the fact is not , anyone can find the fallacy in my understanding ?

P.S. I only have some basic knowledge of Calculus .

Comment: The problem is with definitions. If you don't define your concepts clearly, then you can't expect to ask a precise question, let alone for a fallacy to be identified. Prior to identifying a fallacy you must formalize your arguments.

Comment: The number of points in a non empty interval is uncountable. Countable infinities are fairly non intuitive, uncountable goes beyond that...

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number like 1 or 2.  It can't be used in equations in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

${0}\cdot\infty={1}$
Never do math with infinity like this. This leads to problems

${1}\cdot\infty={\infty} = {2}\cdot\infty={\infty}$

Therefore,

1 = 2

This is obviously false. We must work with limits approaching infinity, not infinity itself. Also, there are different types of infinities. You are dealing with an uncountable infinity which is more complex to work with. Also, modern calculus was changed from how Leibniz constructed it to avoid things like this.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a segment is not related to the number of points.
You could make just as valid an argument that the grade on your next exam
should be decided by counting the number of hairs on your head.